# Diffusion always present?

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, diffusion

Simply asked: Is diffusion always and everywhere present? Let's reduce the question to the macroscopic world.

Anytime, when two materials touch each other (*air <-> wall, tea <-> cup, chair <-> floor*), will a diffusion process always be present then?
As far as I understand a diffusion covers only the transport of atoms and the like between materials, not within.

edit: According to Vadim's comment, I'd like to stick to diffusion **between** materials.

Comment: You are mistaken - diffusion is a very broad term that includes not only transport between materials: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion

Comment: That's true and obvious..  thank you, I updated the question!

Comment: In other words, you want to know, if, when two materials are brought in contact, there will always be a diffusion of atoms between them?

Comment: Yes :) (have to use the remaining letters...)

Comment: This question is very broad. Can you focus on a single interface under specified conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When two materials A and B are placed in contact with one another, molecules of A will diffuse across the interface into B, and molecules of B will diffuse across the interface into A.  The highest concentration of B in A will be at the interface, and the B concentration will decrease with distance from the interface.  So diffusion of B molecules will be driven by the concentration gradient into A.  The extent of the region where this occurs will increase as time progresses.

In cases where A and B are not mutually miscible, A will first dissolve into B at the interface, and then diffuse inward; similarly for B into A.  This dissolution at the interface will typically be described by Henry's law for gas dissolution in a solid or liquid.

Answer (score 3):

I do not understand the reason for making a difference between the diffusion between or within materials. Of course, there are different diffusion mechanisms, but I do not think those differences are relevant at the level of the present question.

The answer is *yes*, at least as a qualitative answer. However, the quantitative answer may correspond to a *no* in practice.

The reason for the unavoidable presence of diffusion even in the presence of solid materials is the equally unavoidable presence of thermal fluctuations and of many kinds of defects in real solids. The presence of such mechanisms opens different possibilities for atomic diffusion. In some cases, such possibilities may have negligible probability, in other cases, they can provide effective mechanisms for diffusion.